# Tag-it shows no delete-symbol

Tags: tag-it

[image]

I don't know why I don't get the "X" symbol ...

It should be like this:

[image]

How can I find the problem? Maybe an CSS-file is blocking an other CSS-file?

**JavaScript-Code**

```
$(function() {
    var sampleTags = ['Klavier', 'Blockflöte', 'Schlagzeug', 'Gesang', 'Saxophon', 'Klarinette', 'Keyboard', 'Panflöte', 'Mundharmonika', 'Beatboxing', 'Akkordeon', 'Cello', 'Bratsche', 'Tuba', 'Kontrabass', 'E-Gitarre', 'E-Bass', 'Akustikgitarre'];

    $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
        availableTags: sampleTags,
        singleField: true,
        singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField'),

        beforeTagAdded: function(evt, ui) {

            var counter = jQuery.inArray(ui.tagLabel, sampleTags);

            if(counter != -1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $('.tagit-new input').val('');
                return false;
            }
        },

    });
});
```

Comment: the next time post the code using code formatting (ctrl+k or indent all lines with 4 spaces) instead of quote formatting

Comment: Okay! I'm sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

Susanne, encountered the same issue.  After a significant amount of time wasted, I determined that the 'x' icon is present, it's just not rendering on the browser level.

```
var removeTag = $('<a><span class="text-icon">\xd7</span></a>') // \xd7 is an X
```

This is line 485 of tag-it.js; when you check the rendering of your page, you'll see this is actually present.  I changed it to the following in order to confirm that it was present and just needed to be rendered differently.

```
var removeTag = $('<a><span>x</span></a>') // \xd7 is an X
```

It can be styled however, from this point.  Hope this helps anyone encountering this issue.